Exclude certain packages from upgrading while upgrading everything else in Debian
I use Debian Sid, and this one package, Firefox, has an update with a grave bug found with apt-listbugs. I want to exclude that package from upgrading while upgrading everything else. There is a way to do this, but it is tedious with copy and pasting certain packages to upgrade and leaving some packages out. How can I exclude certain packages from upgrading with a single command?

When apt-listbugs finds a critical bug in a package that’s about to be upgraded, it asks you what to do — you can choose to ignore the bug (and proceed with the upgrade), abort the entire upgrade, or pin the buggy package. The latter option will cause it to add pin priorities so that the package is no longer considered for upgrades until the bug is fixed. (See also How do I unpin a package which is pinned by apt-listbugs)
If that’s not working for you, you can manually hold the package:
sudo apt-mark hold firefox

(or firefox-esr). This will also prevent the package from being upgraded until you unhold it.

Thank you for the command.

I found out that typing "p" in the apt-listbugs message will pin it.

FWIW: apt-mark hold <pkgname> also prevents <pkgname> from being removed.
